# reduce function not providing the expected sum

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var result_goals_against = [];
memo_goals.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.player_id]) {
    res[value.player_id] = {
      goals_against: 0,
      player_id: value.player_id
    };
    result_goals_against.push(res[value.player_id])
  }
  res[value.player_id].goals_against += value.goals_against;
  return res;
}, {});
```

This is the output:

[image: Most results are NaN and some have undefined appended a couple of times]

My concern: the real values for row should be (1.row = 10), (6.row = 2) and (0 for the rest), the script should be summing up, but it seems it just chains the values. I have tried to modify `+= value.goals_against;` to `+= +value.goals_against;` as my values in mongodb are strings and not numbers.

> Sample memo data array

```
memo_goals = 
[
{
        "_id" : "Qzg3P8RGakoT3WvRC",
        "match_id" : "f3YWd2WKKz9dCW4CH",
        "team_id" : "2PKzW3Yb27vMqfDYh",
        "player_number" : "7",
        "player_id" : "8KnyCJ3KiqBYmAQ26",
        "saves" : "12",
        "goals_against" : "2"
},
{
        "_id" : "b39KhqCXRFDGccpdW",
        "match_id" : "9bKWj27hF5P87Ags4",
        "team_id" : "2PKzW3Yb27vMqfDYh",
        "player_number" : "7",
        "player_id" : "8KnyCJ3KiqBYmAQ26",
        "saves" : "16"
}
];
```

Comment: Where's the data? I got a feeling you're trying to operate with strings and not numbers here...

Comment: Please show your memo_goals structure and a example of it!

Comment: @cFreed I have added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have 2 problems:

1. If `value.goals_against` is a string (and not a number, as you say), then adding the number `res[value.player_id].goals_against` to the string `value.goals_against` will give you a string, not a number. You need to parse `value.goals_against` as a number before adding it.
2. `value.goals_against` apparently also contains `undefined` values in your data. You need to verify that case and resolve them to 0 in the addition.

To solve the 2 issues above, you could try changing line 10 from:

```
res[value.player_id].goals_against += value.goals_against;
```

...to:

```
res[value.player_id].goals_against += (parseInt(value.goals_against) || 0);
```

Comment: Damn nice! Thx Eduard! I actually tried parseInt, because "+" did not work, but I did not know to add  "|| 0" as well. Glad to have you here. I am about to get my application compeleted and long hours make me unable to discover new things :) I think I have to start to write integers

Comment: Glad I could help! You can show your appreciation by marking the answer as "accepted" and get yourself some well deserved rest ;)

Comment: Would really appreciate it if you would accept the answer ;)

Comment: I would, but where is the button?